# Internet Explorer playing ads in background, possible malware

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, virus, advertisements, adware

I think I may have a virus. The audio of ads keep blasting in the background and I found the source to be internet explorer. Task Manager shows Internet Explorer open in the applications tab but there are no visible windows. When I right click on IE and click **Go to process** nothing happens. In the processes tab, I see 3 `iexplore.exe` processes. Whenever I end them, an hour later the background ads return with IE windowless. I have tried the following AV's and tools but none of them succeeded:

1. Trend Micro Maximum Security
2. Malwarebytes Anti-Malware
3. Junk Ware Removal Tool by Thisisu
4. Hitman Pro
5. AdwCleaner

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

While I was writing this: I noticed a program in the programs and features list called "agederar by ryofward". Could this be the culprit?

Answer (score 1):

[This is known malware.](https://malwr.com/analysis/NmIwYzBmM2Y5ZDU0NDEzYTljMTlhMTJhM2RjOTViNTE/) Among other things, the program runs on startup and tampers with the Internet browser. As for the malware not getting detected by your antimalware software, it's likely that it is taking evasive measures to avoid detection.

Try uninstalling the program and see if the problem persists. You may need to perform scans in Safe Mode to detect the program.